# Why aren't // and m// exactly synonymous?

Tags: regex, raku

From the examples below, I see that `/ /` and `m/ /` aren't exactly synonymous, contrary to what I expected. I thought that the only reason to use `m/ /` instead of `/ /` was that it allows using different delimiters (e.g. `m{ }`). Why are they different and why would I want to use one versus the other?

I am searching for CSV files in a directory. At first I searched for files ending in `csv`, thus (all code shown as seen from the Perl 6 REPL):

```
> my @csv_files = dir( test => / csv $ /  );
["SampleSheet.csv".IO]
```

but recently a file ending in `Csv` showed up. So I tried matching case insensitively:

```
> my @csv_files = dir( test => m:i/ csv $ / );
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

I found that I could fix this by putting a block around the matching expression:

```
> my @csv_files = dir( test => { m:i/ csv $ / } );
["SampleSheet.csv".IO]
```

However, if I had used a block around the original expression it doesn't match with the bare `/ /`, but it does with `m/ /`:

```
> my @csv_files = dir( test => { / csv $ / } );
[]
> my @csv_files = dir( test => { m/ csv $ / } );
["SampleSheet.csv".IO]
```

Then I found out that if I used the case-insensitive adverb inside `/ /`, it does work:

```
> my @csv_files = dir( test => /:i csv $ / );
["SampleSheet.csv".IO]
```

Anyway, `/ /` and `m/ /` are clearly behaving differently and it's not yet clear to me why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The difference between `/.../` and `m/.../`

From [Regexes#Lexical conventions](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Lexical_conventions):

> ```perl6
> m/abc/;         # a regex that is immediately matched against $_ 
> rx/abc/;        # a Regex object 
> /abc/;          # a Regex object
> ```

In other words, it's `/.../` and `rx/.../` that are synonyms, not `/.../` and `m/.../`:

- `/.../` and `rx/.../` return the specified regex as a [`Regex`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Regex) object, without matching it against anything for now.
- `m/.../` immediately matches the specified regex against the string that's stored in the variable`$_` (the so-called "topic"), and returns the result as a [`Match`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Match) object, or as `Nil` if there was no match.

Demonstration:

```perl6
$_ = "Foo 123";

say m/\d+/;        # ｢123｣
say m/\d+/.^name;  # Match

say /\d+/;         # /\d+/
say /\d+/.^name;   # Regex
```

---

## Explanations & comments regarding your code

#### *Applying regex modifiers*

> but recently a file ending in Csv showed up. So I tried matching case insensitively
>
> ```perl6
>  my @csv_files = dir( test => m:i/ csv $ / );
>  Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
>  Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
>    in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
> ```

That code immediately matches the regex against the topic `$_` of the calling scope, which is uninitialized. This involves converting it to a string (which causes the warning `Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context`), and returns `Nil` because there is no match. So you're essentially calling the function as `dir( test => Nil )`.

To make it work, either use `rx` or apply the `:i` adverb inside the regex:

```perl6
my @csv_files = dir( test => rx:i/ csv $ / );
```

```perl6
my @csv_files = dir( test => / :i csv $ / );
```

---

#### *Blocks as smart-matchers*

> I found that I could fix this by putting a block around the matching expression:
>
> ```perl6
> > my @csv_files = dir( test => { m:i/ csv $ / } );
> ```

That works too. What happens here, is:

- `{ ... }` creates a block that takes a single argument (which is available as `$_` inside the block).
- The `m:i/ ... /` inside the block matches against `$_`, and returns a `Match`.
- Because the `m:i/.../` is the last statement in the block, its `Match` becomes the return value of the block.
- The `test` adverb of the `dir` function accepts any smart-matcher, which includes not just `Regex` objects but also `Block` objects (see the documentation for the [smart-match operator `~~`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_~~)).

---

#### *Using a `Regex` as a `Bool`*

> However, if I had used a block around the original expression it doesn't match with the bare / /, but it does with m/ /:
>
> ```perl6
> > my @csv_files = dir( test => { / csv $ / } );
> []
> ```

When a block is used as a smart-matcher, it is first called and then its return value is coerced to a `Bool`: `True` means it matched, and `False` means it didn't.

In this case, your block always returs a `Regex` object.

Coercing a regex object to a boolean, immediately matches it against the current `$_`, and returns `True` if the regex matched, and `False if it didn't:

```perl6
say /\d+/.Bool;  # False

$_ = "123";
say /\d+/.Bool;  # True
```

So in your code, the regex ends up being repeatedly checked against `$_`, rather than against the filenames:

```perl6
$_ = "abc";
.say for dir test => { / \d+ / }  # Returns no filenames

$_ = "abc 123";
.say for dir test => { / \d+ / }  # Returns all filenames
```

---

#### *Filtering files by their extension*

> I am searching for CSV files in a directory. At first I searched for files ending in csv, thus (all code shown as seen from the Perl 6 REPL):
>
> ```perl6
> > my @csv_files = dir( test => / csv $ /  );
> ```

This doesn't just find files that have the CSV extension, but **all** files that end in the three letters `cvs`, including ones like `foobarcsv` or `foobar.xcsv`.
Here are two better ways to write it if you only want CSV files:

```perl6
my @csv-files = dir test => / ".csv" $ /;
```

```perl6
my @csv-files = dir.grep: *.extension eq "csv"
```

Or the case-insensitive version:

```perl6
my @csv-files = dir test => / :i ".csv" $ /;
```

```perl6
my @csv-files = dir.grep: *.extension.lc eq "csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for going the second mile and providing the comprehensive `Explanations & comments regarding your code` section!