# Any difference between m and rx?

Tags: regex, syntax, raku

They seem to be [used interchangeably in the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-quote_%2F_%2F-quote_rx-quote_m-Lexical_Conventions). Is there any difference, even in intent?

Comment: The link at the very beginning said that `m/.../` is a regex that is immediately matched against $_. Isn't that the difference?

Comment: Yes, the article you're linking to points out the differences. `rx/.../`, like `/.../`, is a regex object with which you can match, whereas `m/.../` returns the match directly.

Comment: @SimonShine but they are used interchangeably in the rest of the text. besides, `say 'ðu' ~~ rx/.u/; say 'ðu' ~~ m/.u/;  #OUTPUT: «｢ðu｣␤｢ðu｣␤» `m` is not matching against the $_ 'immediately'

Comment: `m/.../` is analagous to an **explicitly and always immediately invoked** block of code like `{ say 42 }()` whereas `/.../` or `rx/.../` are analagous to a block of code like `{ say 42 }` which is **either** implicitly immediately invoked if it's in statement/sink context **or** just a block of code, not yet invoked, when it's used as a value.

Comment: @jjmerelo Interesting point. `m/.../`, used on RHS of `~~`, clearly does not technically match **immediately**. Instead it's immediately **after** the `~~` operator has set `$_` to its LHS argument. This is presumably related to the fact that `~~` is "a special form handled directly by the compiler".

Comment: (Just for a sense of completeness, I'm pretty sure `rx/.../` and `/.../` are interchangeable.)

Comment: See also [Why aren't // and m// exactly synonymous?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331353/215487)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the documentation you link to states,

> ```
> m/abc/;         # a regex that is immediately matched against $_
> rx/abc/;        # a Regex object
> /abc/;          # a Regex object
> ```
>
> *[...]* Example of difference between `m/ /` and `/ /` operators:
>
> ```
> my $match;
> $_ = "abc";
> $match = m/.+/; say $match; say $match.^name; # OUTPUT: «｢abc｣␤Match␤» 
> $match =  /.+/; say $match; say $match.^name; # OUTPUT: «/.+/␤Regex␤»
> ```

So `/.../` returns a `Regex` object that can be passed around as a value, and be used for matching later on and multiple times, and `m/.../` returns a `Match` object having immediately performed the match. When you print a `Match` object, you get the result of the match, and when you print a `Regex` object, you get a textual representation of the regex. Using `m/.../` in Perl 6 lets you access the implicit `Match` object, `$/`:

> Match results are stored in the `$/` variable and are also returned from the match. The result is of type `Match` if the match was successful; otherwise it is `Nil`.

The distinction is comparable to Python's [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects) vs. [`re.match`/`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), and a similar distinction exists in Perl 5 where you can store and re-use a regex with `qr/.../` vs. `m/.../` and `/.../` for direct matching. As @raiph points out, not all occurrences of `m/.../` and `/.../` result in direct matching. Conversely, [Perl 5 precompiles literal (static) regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952998/is-there-a-way-to-precompile-a-regex-in-perl) even when not explicitly asking it to. (Presumably, Perl 6 performs this optimization, too.)

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment before noting that your edit relied on me leaving it in for details. But I cover the same point in my comment on the question. In P5 regexes are *strings* that may be compiled if they're entirely static. In P6 regexes are *code* that's always compiled but may have dynamic elements.